# How to backward-kill-word in Vim insert mode like zsh?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, insert-mode

I'm re-learning Vim. My question is that I want to <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>⌫</kbd> to backward-delete a word in **INSERT MODE**. I've spent some days to achieve this (and succeeded) to my `zsh` shell through `bindkey` in `.zshrc` file (not related to Vim though), but now in Vim this problem occurs again. So my question is how to bind this action **backward-kill-word** to the key combination?

Comment: Are you looking for `:h i_CTRL-W`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is instead of trying to bind a key combination to this action, just use the default key binding for it, which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

See [`:help i_CTRL-W`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-W).

This same key binding should be available by default in zsh (or bash, etc.) so you could just use it everywhere with no need for custom configuration.

You could try to map <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> to do the same in Vim... But it's hard to tell whether that will work for you right away, since mappings with the <kbd>Option</kbd> key can be tricky to get right... In theory, this should be the way to map it:

```
noremap! <M-BS> <C-w>
```

But whether that's going to work depends on your terminal and Vim configuration and possibly on which kind of terminal emulator you're using...

**UPDATE:** From your answer, it seems <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> actually produces Shift+Insert on your terminal (perhaps through some configuration of yours.)

So you might want to use this mapping:

```
noremap! <S-Insert> <C-w>
```

Using `map!` instead of `imap` will make the <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌫</kbd> also work in command-line mode (when you start a command with `:`, or also when you start search with `/`.)

You should use `nore` (non-recursive) mappings in most cases. See [“Strict Mapping”](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) from Steve Losh’s “Learn Vimscript the Hard Way” for a great explanation of why you usually want that. Vim documentation also mentions it under [`:help recursive_mapping`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#recursive_mapping).

Comment: lol, I'm writing an answer while I see your answer, from the comment I actually solved this problem. Just a short question: I don't understand `noremap`'s meaning, does it mean no-remap? So I don't want the result to be remapped again? Still great thanks for your kindness!

Comment: Glad you found it! It's actually `nore-map` and the `nore` means non-recursive. (See `:help recursive_mapping`.) It means it will always use the original Vim meaning of `<C-w>` (which is backward-kill-word), even if you end up remapping `<C-w>` to something else in a separate mapping. You usually want to use `nore` mappings, with few exceptions. That way, even if you remap something used in the expansion, the mapping won't be affected by the new mappings.

Comment: Actually, here's the best explanation for that: https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html

Comment: Updated my answer to include all that.

Comment: I think I have read the best one from the second comment, very clear to me!

Answer (score 1):

(First I think I have to say is that my environment is simply **Terminal** and **zsh**, all I use are built-in stuffs provided by macOS.)

In *INSERT MODE* I typed <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>⌫</kbd> then strangely

```
<S-Insert>
```

appeared (I think this is because I modified the Terminal preferences to make <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>⌫</kbd> be mapped to `\033[2;2~`) , then I used the following and it works:

```
imap <S-Insert> <C-W>
```

(But actually I don't know what's the difference between `imap` and `inoremap` as the docs is a bit long and I decided to try-then-confirm rather than reading.)